# Is there any optimized way for pre selecting the option on page refresh using php only other than the basic way of using if statement in every option?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

What I have:

A custom post type named bookings inside which
I am using Meta box in wordpress for plugin development.

What I want:

when the user select the specific option and clicks on update in my custom post type named bookings then the value remains saved.

Even on Page Refresh.

What is happening:

My value is getting stored inside  the requested variable but I am unable to bind the value of the variable with my select tag. I have been able to achieve the result with the help of if condition but that is not the best way I think,

so I wanted to ask if their is any other way to achieve this other than
this:

```
if($frequency == 'One-Time') echo"selected"
```

Code I'm using:

```
function meta_box2() {

 add_meta_box(

    'custom2', // $id
    'What Needs To Be Done?', // $title
    'meta_box2_fun', // $callback
    'bookings', // $screen
    'normal', // $context
    'high' // $priority
 );
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'meta_box2' );

//.................Second Meta Box Function...........................

function meta_box2_fun($post){

 $frequency = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'frequency-save', true );

 $bathroom = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bathroom-save', true );

 $bedroom = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bedroom-save', true );
?>

<label for="Frequency">Frequency</label>

<select name = "frequency" >
  <option value = "One-Time">One-Time</option>
  <option value = "Weekly">Weekly</option>
  <option value = "Every Other Week">Every Other Week</option>
  <option value = "Every 4 Weeks">Every 4 Weeks</option>
  <option value = "Every Monday & Friday">Every Monday&Friday</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<label for="bathroom">Bathroom</label>

<select name = "bathroom">
  <option value = "1">  1  </option>
  <option value = "1.5">1.5</option>
  <option value = "2">  2  </option>
  <option value = "2.5">2.5</option>
  <option value = "3">  3  </option>
  <option value = "3.5">3.5</option>
</select>

<label for="bedroom">Bedroom</label> 

<select name = "bedroom" value = "bedroom">
  <option  value="0" >0</option>
  <option  value="1" >1</option>
  <option  value="2" >2</option>
  <option  value="3" >3</option>
  <option  value="4" >4</option>
  <option  value="5" >5</option>
</select>
```

```
function meta_box2_save($post_id){

 if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
  return;

update_post_meta($post_id, 'frequency-save',$_POST['frequency']);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'bathroom-save', $_POST['bathroom']);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'bedroom-save', $_POST['bedroom']);

}

add_action('save_post', 'meta_box2_save');
```

Comment: all down voters please comment where i am wrong as i am new to plugin development so your comments will help build my foundation.

Answer (score 1):

Try  to add option values in array, after that match $frequency with option value, if it is equal add another variable $select = "selected", using this you don't have to repeat the code again and again. You just have to add new values in array.Like I am giving you an example please check below

```
$frequency_opt_val = array('one_time' => "one time", ....);
echo "<select name = "frequency" >";
foreach($frequency_opt_val as $key => $value ){
    $select = '';
    if( $frequency ==  $key  ) $select = 'SELECTED';
    echo "<option value='".$key."' ".$select.">" . $value . "</option>";
}
echo"</select>";
```

Comment: But what if the values of the options in select tag are coming dynamically using api that is the reason we can't use if and only have to do something with the variable $frequency